# PHP fetch associated results from mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

​
Hi, i dont know where im going wrong here, but when i get the results for the query it duplicates the results with a new instance for each associated result?

where i would expect:

1st line:     start time > job > Bus etc...

2ndline:   1st customer name > address etc....

3rd line:   2nd customer name > address blah blah

i actually get

1st line:     start time > job > Bus etc...

2ndline:   1st customer name > address etc....

3rdline:   start time > job > Bus etc...

4thline:   1st customer name > address etc....

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT mrbs_participants.username,mrbs_entry.room_id, mrbs_entry.id, mrbs_entry.start_time, mrbs_entry.name, mrbs_entry.fee, mrbs_users.display_name, mrbs_users.address, mrbs_users.town, mrbs_users.postcode, mrbs_users.home_number FROM mrbs_entry LEFT JOIN mrbs_participants ON mrbs_entry.id = mrbs_participants.entry_id LEFT JOIN mrbs_users ON mrbs_participants.username = mrbs_users.name where from_unixtime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() AND driver = 'Tony'");
/////////////////////start of job list/////////////////////
echo '<div id="Tony">';
echo '<br><p><h1>Tony.</h1></p><br>';
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Start Time</th>
<th>Job</th>
<th>Bus</th>
<th>Fee</th>
<th>Start Mileage</th>
<th>End Mileage</th>
<th>Passengers</th>
</tr>";
$lastEntry = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  if (is_null($lastEntry) || $lastEntry != $row['id'])
    {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . date('l d F Y H:i',$row["start_time"]-=3600) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . date($row["room_id"] +=1) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["fee"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["Start Mileage"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["End Mileage"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["Passengers"] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$lastEntry = $row['id']; }
   else 
   {echo "<span>" . $row["username"] . $row["address"] . $row["town"] . "</span>";}
    
}
if (!is_null($lastEntry)) 

{
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

  ////// end of customer list////////////
```

​

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array) for the `mode` parameter.

Comment: You are working with 3 table at 1????

Comment: Please make 3 table name to short and id verify the id numbers.

Comment: Also, have you run your query directly against the database to see if you get the result you expect?

Comment: Problem... Between 2nd LEFT JOIN and 3rd LEFT JOIN....  There are mix and match each another....

Comment: You must run separately first.... And call Left Join.... There is common 4 types of JOIN in sql....

Comment: @AsifUzZaman What problem are you talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232597/discussion-between-asif-uz-zaman-and-el-vanja).

Comment: @El_Vanja..... There are 3 table join here 2nd and 3rd join seems like bit same... So maybe there is the issue...

Comment: @AsifUzZaman No, that's a perfectly legitimate join. Joins `a` to `b`, then `b` to `c`.